How long does it take for Amazon to approve a new Android app
I am trying to get an app published on Amazon apps.  How long does it normally take and what is the waiting process? This is for an android mobile app.
I have not been able to determine if they are even still up. All of the apps look very old, when I try to download one it says it is not compatible with my modern version of Android

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic
